# Please help me find the author/title of this book

Tags: story-identification, horror

WARNING: Graphic

All I remember about this fantasy horror book is the following:

There is a killer that can stop time. He is searching (or chasing) the protagonist. There is one graphic sequence, where the killer stops time, and is going after the main hero, and the world around them is frozen - they move past frozen people, and the killer rips off their limbs and such (I think there is also reference to how much pain they will feel once they "wake" up).

I was reading S.K and Koontz at the time, but I don't know if it was either of them. I think the book had the word "train" in the title...

P.S.: If this is the wrong place  to ask, can someone refer me to the proper one? I've been meaning to find this out for a long time, but always put it aside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it:
[Dragon Tears, Dean Koontz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Tears)